# Creating a map of population density using shapefiles in R

Tags: r

This would be a pretty simple task for me in ArcGIS, but I'm trying to start using R and I'm stumped. I have census data in the form of a shapefile that contains the population of each shape in the shapefile. I would like to divide the population by the area of each shape in order to create a density map. But I can't figure out how to calculate the area of each shape in the shapefile, and I can't figure out how to take the area once I've calculated it and divide the population by the area.

Comment: Do you know how to read a shapefile into an R object?

Comment: @Spacedman yes! I also know how to map it, etc, I just can't figure out how to calculate the area and manipulate the fields.

Comment: Show us some code - you could be using `sp` or `sf` spatial data in R. You don't use shapefiles in R, you read them into spatial objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

areashp<-readOGR("C:/","Census")
areashp$Totalarea<-area(areashp)
areashp$density<- areashp$population / areashp$Totalarea
```

Also make sure you are in UTM or another projection for calculating area

Using rgeos:

```
library(rgeos)
areashp$Totalarea<-gArea(areashp, byid=TRUE)
areashp$density<- areashp$population / areashp$Totalarea
```

Alternatively, as per Jeffrey's comment you could use: `areashp$density<- areashp$population / rgeos::gArea(areashp, byid=TRUE)` if you don't want area in your attribute table.

Comment: Why add a spurious "area" column to the data and import an entire package into the namespace when you only need one function? Just use: areashp$density<- areashp$population / rgeos::gArea(areashp, byid=TRUE)

Comment: Personal preference? I come from Arc where the geometries are in the attribute table already.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯